# limit of the determinant of $n\times n$ matrix over $n!$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $d_n$ denote the determinant of the following $n\times n$ matrix

$M=\begin{bmatrix}
   2       & 1 & 1&1 & \dots & 1 \\
   1       & 3 & 1&1 & \dots &1 \\
   1 &1&4&1 &\dots &1  \\
    1       & 1&1 & \ddots & 1 & 1\\1&1 &\dots&\dots&n &1\\ 1&1 &\dots&\dots&\dots &n+1
\end{bmatrix}
$

What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{d_n}{n!}$?

For $n=1, \det(M)=2,  \frac{d_1}{1!}=2$.

For $n=2, \det(M)=5,  \frac{d_2}{2!}=\frac{5}{2}$.

For $n=3,\det(M)=17,  \frac{d_3}{3!}=\frac{17}{6} $.

It looks like the sequence is increasing. But figuring out $d_n$ is tricky. I'm not sure if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices will help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you run into this problem?

Comment: May be the obvious sequence of row operations reveals something?

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: the matrix is the one-dimensional perturbation of the diagonal matrix with entries $1,2,\ldots,n$ on the main diagonal. The one-dimensional perturbation is of the form $Ax=n\langle x,v\rangle \,v$ where $v$ is the vector with all coordinates equal $n^{-1/2}.$

Comment: After you subtract the bottom row from all the others, and then develop the determinant along that bottom row it looks like we get something that is roughly of the form $n!$ multiplied by a harmonic sum. Strongly suggesting that the ratio grows without bound.

Comment: Numerical experiments strongly suggest that $\dfrac{d_{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \dfrac{d_n}{n!} + \dfrac1{n+1}$ for all $n\ge1$. If established (probably @JyrkiLahtonen's comments are the way) this would imply that the limit is $\infty$ since harmonic series.

Comment: Yup. I got
$$\det(M)=n!(\frac{n+1}n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k).$$

Comment: The matrix is $D+ee^T$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,\ldots,n)$. Therefore $\frac{\det(M)}{n!}=\frac{\det(M)}{\det(D)}=1+e^TD^{-1}e=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$, which is unbound.

Answer (score 3):

You can define $A$ as $n\times n$ matrix with all entries $1$ and $B=diag(1,2,...n)$ and then $M=A+B$. Then
we can use the determinant of sum of two matrix formula as in the following result:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ square matrix on any field, then
$$\det(A+B)=\sum\limits_{\alpha ,\beta } {{{( - 1)}^{s(\alpha ) + s(\beta )}}\det A[\alpha |\beta ]\det B(\alpha |\beta )} $$
where the summation ranges for $\alpha ,\beta  \subseteq {\rm{\{ }}1,2,....,n\}$ satisfying Card($\alpha$)=Card($\beta$) and  $s:P(\{ 1,2,...,n\} ) \to {N }$ is defined as the sum of all elements in a subset of $\{1,2,...,n\}$(by convention , it maps empty set to zero),$P$ means the power set. Note here that $A[\alpha|\beta]$ means the matrix block of $A$ with rows $\alpha$ and columns $\beta$ and $B(\alpha|\beta)$ means the matrix block of $B$ excluding rows of $\alpha$ and columns of $\beta$.

Then we can see by $A,B$, the only non-zero $\det A[\alpha|\beta]\det B(\alpha|\beta)$ is when $\alpha=\beta=\emptyset$ or when $\alpha=\beta$ being a singleton. Then we can find that when $\alpha=\beta=\emptyset$, the summand is $\det(B)=n!$ and when $\alpha=\beta=k=1,2,...,n$, the $\det A[\alpha|\beta]=1$ and the $\det B(\alpha|\beta)=n(n-1)...(k-1)(k+1)...1$ and thus we see det(M)=$n!+\sum_{k=1,2,...,n} n!/k$ and thus we see $\det(M)/n!=1+\sum_{k=1,2,...n}1/k=1+1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n$ is unbounded when $n$ goes to infinity!!!